# Why do equal strings sometimes behave differently? (VB.NET COM interface)

Tags: vb.net, com-interop, tostring

**Example:**

```
Dim Sh32 As Object = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim path As String = "C:\temp\catalog.zip"
Dim sf As Object = Sh32.NameSpace(path)
```

*-> does not work, sf = Nothing*

```
Dim Sh32 As Object = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Dim path As String = "C:\temp\catalog.zip"
Dim sf As Object = Sh32.NameSpace(path.ToString)
```

*-> works*

Any idea?

Clearly path = path.ToString, but they behave differently when used as COM parameters.

Comment: Why are you using COM for this? The Process class should be able to do anything Shell.Application can do.

Comment: Thanks, but I use sf.MoveHere(newpath.ToString) to add a file to a zip file, and there is no equivalent feature in the Process class. The ZipPackage class of the .NET framwork is an alternative but it always adds a meta file [ContentType].xml.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, I don't know the details of VB and/or COM well enough, but maybe there is a difference between a string **object** and a string **representation**?

Should be interesting to see someone "in the know" resolving the puzzle ;)

Comment: The string type's implementation of ToString() is "return this" so that shouldn't have any effect at all. (And no, there's no difference between a string object and its representation - they're both strings.)

Comment: I performed a series of additional tests and found out that it even suffices to double the round brackets in the statement to make it work: Dim sf As Object = Sh32.NameSpace((path)). My conclusion so far is that it is an issue of the VB.NET IL compiler